# Updating template for bibliographic record output

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I am using `biblatex-chicago` to format a bibliography. I need to ensure that records with type `phdthesis` are specified as such. Here is an example of a record I have:

```
@phdthesis{edgeworth1991,
  title = {The Act of Discovery: An Ethnography of the Subject-Object Relation in Archaeological Practice.},
  author = {Edgeworth, Matt},
  year = {1991},
  school = {Durham University},
}
```

Currently it displays like this:

> Edgeworth, Matt. 1991. “The Act of Discovery: An Ethnography of the Subject-
> Object Relation in Archaeological Practice.” Durham University.

and I would like it to look like this (added part in bold):

> Edgeworth, Matt. 1991. “The Act of Discovery: An Ethnography of the Subject-
> Object Relation in Archaeological Practice.” **PhD Thesis.** Durham University.

I would appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Can you please share a full example document that cites this entry? If I try to build one (https://gist.github.com/moewew/6e2da540fb1207d568e86681485f4ad2) I get "PhD diss., Durham University, 1991.": https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRIZ8.png. The output of these kind of localised strings may depend on your language settings, so it is crucial that we see a complete document that reproduces your setup with as little code as possible.

Comment: Any news here? As I mentioned above I failed to reproduce the output you show, so it is likely that something additional is going on at your side (code not yet shown in the question that changes the output, outdated package versions ...). Please show us a small example document in the spirit of what I linked to above that reproduces what you are getting at the moment with as little code as possible.

Comment: I apologize for the delay, I have notifications turned off. The problem was actually with the data input. I am using Zotero to manage my references, and while the "Item Type" field was set to "Thesis", I did not realize that biblatex parses the contents of the "Type" field to produce the content I needed to add. So it was resolved by simply adding "PhD Thesis" to the "Type" field in the Zotero record. For more details on what "Type" strings map to what biblatex values, see https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/94317/thesis-type-not-being-exported-to-bib-file